# How to make the default Gmail account different from Chrome profile account?

Tags: gmail, google-chrome, google-multi-login

I've tried other solutions to change the default Gmail account but they have only worked temporarily on Chrome. My Chrome is set to sync with the account with email A (and I want it to stay that way) but I want my default Gmail account to be email B. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

closest you can get is to set your Account B as "another person". then you will be:

- signed in into Account A (not necessarily - you can log out and still be synched with Chrome)
- signed in into Account B at the same time and use it as default

to set it up:

- click on that button on top right of the browser (shown on image)
- window opens and then click on **ADD PERSON**
- when done just login into your Gmail from "new person" and stay logged in

[image]